# How do I create a deb for GCC 4.7?

Tags: 10.10, compiling, deb, packaging, gcc

I'm sorry but I have tried the tutorials on various websites. Nothing, so far, has worked. I'm using Ubuntu Maverick 10.10. I've downloaded, compiled and installed GCC 4.7.0. Now I want to make a .deb file of the GCC 4.7.0. Could anybody give me the sure steps to creating a GCC 4.7.0 .deb file? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to make a .deb file of a source package for *personal installation/uninstallation only*, NOT for distribution

> *Warning:* Note that packaging a source package for *distribution* via PPA or even via plain .deb is quite complicated and you should start off with [this guide and its links](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage) as well as [this other guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html) in that case. I have also found the `#debian-mentors` channel on the official Debian IRC to be a great situation-specific resource for beginning packagers/devs.

**To create a deb for personal use**, the easy solution for most cases is to simply use `checkinstall`, which will create a .deb file that you can not only install on other (compatible) systems with the appropriate dependencies installed, but also allows you to uninstall the package. **Note** that GCC is a large and complex package, so `checkinstall` may not work with it!

- `sudo apt-get install checkinstall -y`
- When done with `make`, run `checkinstall` instead of `make install`
- *checkinstall* will install your application AND give you a .deb file in the current (source) folder which you can simply copy and install on other systems with `dpkg -i`
- Use `dpkg -r application-name` to remove the application at any time (should also work from Synaptic)

  - Please see this [community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) and the [author's home page](http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) if you need more information.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply so late but your answer was very good. I use checkinstall now frequently. It fails about 25% of the time but I can always debug the process when that happens. It's so strange that this app is not included in the Ubuntu standard package!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Guide:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html

Comment: I don't want a guide, I just want a quick answer but thank you. The best quick answer I got was the: checkinstall --install=yes
I think I found that answer somewhere else. Sometimes that checkinstall fails but more often than not, it succeeds.